# statsmodels add_constant for OLS intercept, what is this actually doing?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

Reviewing linear regressions via statsmodels OLS fit I see you have to use add_constant to add a constant '1' to all your points in the independent variable(s) before fitting. However my only understanding of intercepts in this context would be the value of y for our line when our x equals 0, so I'm not clear what purpose always just injecting a '1' here serves. What is this constant actually telling the OLS fit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't add a constant to your values, it adds a constant term to the linear equation it is fitting.  In the single-predictor case, it's the difference between fitting an a line `y = mx` to your data vs fitting `y = mx + b`.

Comment: so all the constant is doing is indicating there *is* a "b" in the equation?

Comment: @TimLindsey: In essence, yes.  It tells the model to fit a value for `b` as well as coefficients for your predictors.  I've never really understood why statsmodels requires you to add this explicitly, since as described [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model) you pretty much always want to do it unless you have a specific justification for not doing so.

Answer (score 9):

sm.add_constant in statsmodel is the same as sklearn's fit_intercept parameter in LinearRegression(). If you don't do sm.add_constant or when LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False), then both statsmodels and sklearn algorithms assume that b=0 in y = mx + b, and it'll fit the model using b=0 instead of calculating what b is supposed to be based on your data.