Slope and intercept of robust regression Python statsmodels RLM
I would like to find the slope and intercept of a robust regression computed using statsmodels.api.RLM from Python statsmodels. I have calculated the regression and viewed the summary, but I do not see intercept as part of the summary. Where can I find this information?
Test code:
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

# Toy data with a slope of ~1 and an intercept of ~0
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
y = np.array([0.5, 0.3, 1, 1.5, 4, 4, 4.2, 4.8, 4.7, 5, 
             5.9, 5.6, 6.2, 7, 7.7, 8, 8.2, 9, 9.6, 9.8])

# Generate the model
rlm_model = sm.RLM(y, x, M=sm.robust.norms.TukeyBiweight())
rlm_results = rlm_model.fit()

# View results
rlm_results.summary()



you need to add a constant (vector of ones) to your x matrix. It is not added by default unless formula is used. see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404817/statsmodels-add-constant-for-ols-intercept-what-is-this-actually-doing
